# How to trigger one app from another app in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, launch, url-scheme

I want create an app using ios Swift, where **first app can launch second app on click of the button**. I am able to launch web Url's on click of the button but not the application. Please guide me through how to provide the URL scheme for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please look through the custom url scheme in iOS topics.

This [link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) might help you with that.

If you define custom url scheme for your second application. You can call that url from your first app when a button is pressed.

Comment: It's always helpful to check for the target application via `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:targetURL]`.